# How to exclude feedback messages from a specific child component/container?

Tags: filter, wicket, feedback, wicket-6

I would like to filter messages coming to my feedback panel by excluding a specific child component or container. Is there a way to do this?

Wicket currently has a `ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter` and `ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter`. The container will filter everything from children of the specified container while the component one filters only from that component.

My goal is to have all components except the specified one display their feedback messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create your own implementation of IFeedbackMessageFilter and iterate through the message reporter's parents to see if one of the parents is a class you'd like to exclude from reporting to the parent feedback panel.

This is a little hacky with the class checking but it works for what I needed:

```
public class ExcludeClassFeedbackMessageFilter implements IFeedbackMessageFilter {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8104563974910018990L;

private MarkupContainer parentContainer;

private Class<?>[] classes;

public ExcludeClassFeedbackMessageFilter(MarkupContainer parentContainer, Class<?>... classes) {
    this.parentContainer = parentContainer;
    this.classes = classes;
}

@Override
public boolean accept(FeedbackMessage message) {
    Component reporter = message.getReporter();

    boolean foundExcludedComponent = false;

    Component parent = reporter.getParent();

    while (!(parent.equals(parentContainer))) {
        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            if (parent.getClass().getName().contains(clazz.getName())) {
                foundExcludedComponent = true;
            }
        }
        parent = parent.getParent();
    }
    return !foundExcludedComponent;
}
}
```

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain the reason? Is this not a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Roll your own IFeedbackMessageFilter that accepts from any component but the one you want to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks @martin-g I did end up doing this, but would have appreciated more detail in your answer.

Comment: The idea of teaching is not to do your work but to give you a hint so you can improve yourself. Next time you will not need a hint ;-)